# Dojo Enhanced Grid - Pagination : Change the string format of the "Current Position Display" description

Tags: javascript, pagination, dojo, dojox.grid

I am using DOJO Enhanced grid with pagination plugin. I am trying to change the text of the description which is shown for current position display in the grid. Currently it is showing as "1-25 of 200 items" which should be changed to "1-25 of 200 Docs"

I referred below documentation where its mentioned as "Also, the user can specify the string to use to display the type of item.", but didnt provided the details. I have searched many places but couldnt find any solution.

[Dojo grid Pagination Plugin Documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Pagination.html)

If any one done this change, can you please guide me how to change that text. Below is my JSFiddle example where I am trying to change the name.

http://jsfiddle.net/vinaybvk/rpmwzqu4/1/
Following is how I am configuring the pagination to the enhanced grid:

```
  `plugins: {
      pagination: {
          pageSizes: ["25", "50", "100", "All"],
          description: true,
          sizeSwitch: true,
          pageStepper: true,
          gotoButton: true,
          maxPageStep: 4,
          position: "bottom"
      }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it with the itemTitle configuration argument:

```
plugins: {
      pagination: {
          pageSizes: ["25", "50", "100", "All"],
          description: true,
          sizeSwitch: true,
          pageStepper: true,
          gotoButton: true,
          maxPageStep: 4,
          position: "bottom",
          itemTitle: "Docs"
      }
    }
```

This works for the 1.6 version of dojo. In later versions the behaviour of the dojox Enhanced Grid and its Pagination plugin has changed.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the input & notifying it changes in later versions. Its an old implementation Dojo is not upgraded, when we do a revamp to upgrade to newer version of DOJO will keep a look for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the pagination bar and it doesn't seem to have a property for this. You can try and fetch `dojoattachpoint="descriptionDiv"`
This div has the actual message and you can modify it the way you want.
'items' is coming from nls (`description: '${0} - ${1} of ${2} items.'`) and by default, it is 'items'.